# How can I get a dynamic page from its url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url-routing

I have a page where some Dynamic  questions are found. 
When I click on one of the questions, it opens the questions content in another page. 
When that question page opens , the url isn't specific for that question it's just "viewquestion.html" but If I opened that link, it wont direct me to that question.

I append the questions id to the url when I click on the question.

```
function getQuestionData(data) {
var myurl="ViewPost.html";
myurl+= "?QuestionId='" +localStorage["QuestionID"]+"'"; 
window.location.replace(myurl);
```

}

& at the "viewquestion" page, I'm supposed to check the id at the url and get that question from the database. But I don't know how can I do it ?

I'm wondering if this a right idea, & whether I can find a better idea to do this ?

Comment: Can you show us an example (life page, or JSFiddle)?

Comment: Sounds viable. Append the url as viewquestion.html?id=question_id. If you don't want to show the id in the url, you can set up a form and submit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong way to do this.  You need to look at your user requirements and decide if there is a need to link directly to the new page.  If there is, then it would be great to put the required information in the URL so that the users can share links.

Just remember there is a limit to the length of a URL, so make sure you only need a few query string parameters to get to the data you need.